# Replacing items in comma delimited cell with same string each time

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I'm trying to create a formula that will replace any contents of comma delimited cell with single string. The number of items in delimited cell will vary...

Specifically:

`524352435,2345235523,2345235235,sfdsfsdsf,423534534` needs to become `1,1,1,1,1`

`1231231,bbssdds,464574745` needs to become `1,1,1`

Any thoughts greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: =REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,",\w+",",1"),"\w+,","1,")

Comment: This is amazing - the dark arts of REGEXREPLACE. 8•) How should I adapt this to work if there is only one item (ie no comma delimiter) - Thanks

Comment: figured it out - thanks @Oleg_S ... ```=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,",\w+",",1"),"\w+,","1,"),"\w+","1")```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE($Q26:Q,"\w+","1"))
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]